# Text in Prefabs is Empty

Tags: unity-game-engine

i have created a text and under text there are two input fields. then i have created a prefabs of them and instantiated through code. and its working, but problem is the instantiated object is empty and does not show anything just a box, is there any solution to the problem i'm facing of.

Here is my code

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections; 

using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SubmitButton : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject objects;

public void Start () {

 //        Debug.Log ("ok");
}

 public void InstantiateButton () {
 objects.transform.position = new Vector3 (57.4f, 381.58f, 0f);    
 Instantiate (Resources.Load ("Prefabs/Bupivacaine"), new Vector3 (57.4f, 
 381.58f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
}
}
```

Comment: is your Prefabs folder in the Resources folder?

Comment: yes sir its like Resources Folder then Prefabs Folder then there is prefab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To instantiate a UI object, you must make sure its a root child of a Canvas.
So you should change your instantiating method:

```
Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/Bupivacaine"), GameObject.Find("parentNamehere").transform);
```

enter the name of the parent gameobject in "parentNamehere" and remember: it must be a child of a canvas or the canvas itself.

Comment: Don't use `GameObject.Find` if you can avoid it.  Instantiate returns the instantiated object.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to display UI on the Canvas then you need to parent your prefab to the canvas.

```
go.transform.SetParent(canvasGo.transform, false);
```

Comment: i have parented my prefab to the panel in the canvas

Comment: @MohassanNoon try setting localScale to Vector.one

Comment: sir it only shows the 4 rectangular lines and its 2d application , and i have created a button which will genrate  prefabs when it pressed, and each prefabs will be in scrollview, but the thing is i could not go further when the first prefab is empty

Comment: each prefab has one simple text and two input fields,

Comment: @MohassanNoon The code you have provided doesn't parent the instantiated object to the canvas, it leaves it under scene root.  Either pass Instantiate a transform to parent to, or set the parent afterwards using `SetParent` (the former is more resource friendly).

Comment: @Draco18s sir how can i set the alignment of the prefabs as it comes way to bottom

Comment: That's all controlled by the RectTransform's properties. The anchor and min/max X/Y values.  I always work on my prefabs in the place that they'll be spawned so that I can get those values correct.  As I don't know your setup I can't tell you what to set those values to.  I can tell you that I tend to set the min/max values to (0,0);(1,1) with a pivot of (0,1) for things that go into scrolling lists.  It anchors them to the top-left of the scroll content RectTransform.